# DropDownList doesn't postback on SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm writing an ASP.Net webform with some DropDownList controls on it. Then user changes selected item in one of dropdowns, ASP.Net doesn't seem to handle SelectedIndexChanged event until form is submitted with a 'Submit' button click.
How do I make my dropdowns handle SelectedIndexChanged instantly?

P.S. It's a classic question I have answered too many times, but it seems no one asked it before on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Setting the [AutoPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback(VS.71).aspx) property to true will cause it to postback when the selection is changed. Please note that this requires javascript to be enabled.

Comment: Also please note that viewstate must be enabled for the control.

Answer (score 11):

You need to set the `AutoPostBack` property of the list to true.

Also, if you're populating the contents of the drop down list from the code behind (getting the contents of the list from a database, for example) - make sure you're not re-binding the data in every postback.

Sometimes people are caught out by binding the drop-down in the page load event without putting it in an `If Not IsPostBack`.  This will cause the event not to fire.

The same is also true of repeaters and `ItemCommand` events.

Answer (score 4):

if you are populating the dropdown list during page load then each time the page postback it will reload the list thus negating your postback method.
you need to be sure to load the dropdownlist only if (!ispostback)

Comment: This should have been the answer, as lazily setting AutoPostBack="true" does not always work, as it may affect other controls as well. The entire page is posted back!

Answer (score 3):

Set the AutoPostBack property of DropDownList to true.