# dropdownlist won't fire on SelectedItemChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a DDL within an update panel and I cannot get the SelectedItemChanged method to fire when I bind data to it. In Page_Load I have:

```
ddl.DataSource = GetList();
ddl.DataBind();
```

`GetList()` returns a `List<string>`

The values are all there but nothing happens when I select one.

If I am to manually put them in like so:

```
ddl.Items.Add("1");
ddl.Items.Add("2");
ddl.Items.Add("3");
```

it works, why?

The method below is never entered into if I bind the data.

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
    }

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" Width="150px"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109/dropdownlist-doesnt-postback-on-selectedindexchanged ... just add `AutoPostBack="true"` to your DropDownList definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the Change asp:DropDownList does not do postback like button as that is not required in many cases. You have to set it to true to get the postback.

**Change**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" Width="150px"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**To**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" Width="150px" AutoPostBack="true"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 3):

please set the property AutoPostBack="true" on your DropDownList if you have not, this will allow the dropdown to post back any SelectedIndex change